# code is just continue looping.How to solve?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPerson
{
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>TestPerson</code>.
     */
    public TestPerson()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Menus[] menu = { new Menus("Add Member") };
        MemberType[] m = { new MemberType("Corporate Member"), new MemberType("VIP Member") };
        Clubs[] c = { new Clubs("Yoga", "Miss AA"), new Clubs("Kick-boxing", "Mr.AA"), new Clubs("aerobics", "Mrs.Wendy") };
        RegMember[] r = new RegMember[1];
        Cmember cm;
        Vipmember vip;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < menu.length; z++)
        {
            System.out.println((z + 1) + ". " + menu[z].toString());
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter Your selection:");
        int choice = s.nextInt();
        while (choice == 1)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
            {

                System.out.println("\nYour reg no is :" + (RegMember.getNextNo() + 1));
                for (int a = 0; a < m.length; a++)
                {
                    System.out.println((a + 1) + ". " + m[a].toString());
                }
                System.out.println("\nEnter Your selection:");
                int sel = s.nextInt();

                if (sel == 1)
                {
                    s.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter name:");
                    String Name = s.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter Handphone:");
                    String Hpnum = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Age:");
                    int age = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter Company Name:");
                    String CompanyName = s.nextLine();
                    String memberType = "Corporate Member";

                    for (int b = 0; b < c.length; b++)
                    {
                        System.out.println((b + 1) + ". " + c[b].toString());
                    }
                    System.out.println("\nEnter Your selection:");
                    int sel2 = s.nextInt();
                    String clubs = "Yoga";

                    cm = new Cmember(Name, Hpnum, age, CompanyName, memberType, clubs);
                    r[i] = new RegMember(cm);
                }
                else
                {
                    s.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("---You will get a free exercise class---");
                    System.out.println("Enter name:");
                    String Name = s.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter Handphone:");
                    String Hpnum = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Age:");
                    int age = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter Email:");
                    String email = s.next();
                    String memberType = "VIP Member";

                    vip = new Vipmember(Name, Hpnum, age, email, memberType);
                    r[i] = new RegMember(vip);
                }
                s.nextLine();
            }

        }

        displayInfor(r);
    }

    public static void displayInfor(RegMember[] r)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
            System.out.println(r[i].toString());
    }

}
```

I am a beginner for java. I am facing the problem that my code is continue looping.How to solve it?? thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Your `choice` variable is never set to not = 1. Therefore the while loop will continue to run forever.

edit: With the amount of log messages in that code you should be able to see where surely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using If statements as such why not just alter the choice variable manually.
Anyway its too vague your question specify which loop and it would be easier to help